# Unable to handle some characters from a xml response using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to fetch a xml response from server side (java). I checked in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) it gives back the response as expected with 200 as status code, but my Jquery post function is sending the response to error giving me an alert "Error while getting xml from server". Is it a i18n issue? I am able to read and parse other xml responses, how can I do the same with this kind of response

My code:

```
var jqxhr =$.post(redirectMainUrl+"globalaction.action", {
    sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
    action: "getFile",
    absFileName: file_path
},
function(xml1) {
    alert($(xml1).find("lastDayErrorLogs")
                 .children("log")
                 .children("logEvent")
                  .attr("message"));
})
.error(function() {
    if(jqxhr.responseText == 'INVALID_SESSION') {
        alert("Your Session has been timed out");
        window.location.replace(communities); 
    } else {
        alert("Error while getting xml from server");
        goToHomePage();
}
});
```

Response from server (xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="client.xsl"?>
<client version="1.0" >
      <product>
    <lastDayErrorLogs><log>

    <logEvent timestamp="2013-1-15_10:56:6"  severity="1" messageCode="CNX_53021" message="Solicitação inválida recebida." user="" stacktrace="" service="Rep_Service_Prd" serviceType="RS" clientNode="node01_jbpaetlsr2" pid="11900" threadName="11772" context="">
    </logEvent>
    </log></lastDayErrorLogs></product>
</client>
```

Problem causing due to the below attribute's content

```
message="Solicitação inválida recebida."
```

**Update**:

After @Unsung's comment I checked `jqxhr.responseText` it contains the response xml, so I thought to parse the xml inside error function.

but even after making changes to my `error` function I get the following error in Internet Explorer 8

```
Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 22 Jan 2013 06:57:44 UTC


Message: Invalid XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="client.xsl"?>
 <client version="1.0">
  <product>
<lastDayErrorLogs><log>

<logEvent timestamp="2013-1-15_10:56:6"  severity="1" messageCode="CNX_53021" message="Solicita invda recebida." user="" stacktrace="" service="Rep_Service_Prd" serviceType="RS" clientNode="node01_jbpaetlsr002" pid="11900" threadName="11772" context="">
</logEvent>
</log></lastDayErrorLogs></product>
</client>
Line: 2
Char: 10691
Code: 0
URI: http://xxxx:10270/...include/js/jquery.js
```

error function:

```
.error(function() {
    if (jqxhr.responseText == 'INVALID_SESSION') {
        alert("Your Session has been timed out");
        window.location.replace(communities);
    } else {
        alert("Error while getting xml from server");
        var xml=StringtoXML(jqxhr.responseText);
        var csmXmlDoc = $.parseXML( jqxhr.responseText ),
        $csmxml = $( csmXmlDoc ),
        $csmTitle = $csmxml.find("product").children("version");

        alert($csmTitle.text()+", "+$(xml).find("product").children("version").text());
        //goToHomePage();
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you analyse the responseText and see what it is giving? Maybe do an alert of the same?

Comment: why dont you use [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)

Comment: @Unsung: I updated my question stating which character is causing the problem, If I replace **Solicitação inválida** with anything acceptable character, everything works fine

Comment: @Unsung: `jqxhr.responseText` contains the whole xml, but it is unable to parse and get values from it. `alert($(jqxhr.responseText).find("lastDayErrorLogs").children("log").children("logEvent").attr("message"));` does not work, gives me a blank alert

Comment: @Sandeep: I tried it but does not help

Comment: It is possible that the XML document encoding does not match the declared encoding (XML.) That is, the issue is server-side.

Comment: @McDowell: I am setting the response type as `response.setContentType("text/xml")` also the response xml is a content of a file, which is uploaded by user in all cases the encoding is `UTF-8`. Is this creating the problem?

Comment: XML is self-describing, but the declared encoding is just a piece of text; the correct encoder must be used to turn character data into bytes and this must match. Inspect the problem sequence using a hex editor to test this hypothesis. Solicitação is the hex sequence `53 6f 6c 69 63 69 74 61 c3,a7 c3,a3 6f` when encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @McDowell: It's `Solicitação inválida` 2 words that is causing the problem, hex sequence `53 6F 6C 69 63 69 74 61 C3 A7 C3 A3 6F 20 69 6E 
76 C3 A1 6C 69 64 61` but I did not understand, how can I find which encoding it falls in, or is there any other solution? Also both I18n & encoding is same here?

Comment: @AbhishekSimon Looks like an issue with UTF-8 encoding. Why not try some encoding specific to windows? say ISO8859-1 ?

Comment: Well, it looks like the document encoding is OK - that is correct UTF-8 encoded data. It must be some other problem. _I wrote a [small application to help diagnose character issues](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/09/java-character-inspector-application.html) so that is what I use. I18N is a process for enabling software for global markets; it is not a single technical issue._

Comment: @Unsung & @McDowell: `ISO8859-1` worked before setting `UTF-8` as the default encoding type. I needed to assign `UTF-8` as encoding type in java, which solved my problem :)